# Edit midi file via scripting

Tags: midi

I need to programmatically remove a channel (channel 10, hence percussion channel) from a midi file.
There are a lot of music programs that allows you to edit midi files, but i wish i could do this through scripting in order to save some time.

I'm very new to this, and the only thing i have found on the internet that might help me seems to be ffmpeg. But i really don't understand how.

So, in summary:

1. can ffmpeg edit midi files?
2. if yes, is ffmpeg the best tool to script midi manipulations?
3. do you have some working code to show?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many MIDI ↔ text/CSV conversion tools.

Comment: Thanks! could you please name one? Something scriptable

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg is made for audio and video files like `.mp3` and `.mp4`. These are structured very differently than MIDI files. Although it might be possible that someone added MIDI support I doubt it.

Luckily MIDI files are not that hard to understand:

MIDI files are made up of chunks, each chunk starts with four ASCII letters (that take up four bytes in total), followed by a four-byte value. This value is the size of the chunk.

The first chunk always starts with the ASCII letters `MThd`, telling you that this is the header, the next four bytes encode the size. If you skip ahead the number of bytes that the size value told you, you should get to the next chunk, which is a track. If everything is correct you should read the ASCII letters `MTrk`, again followed by a four-byte size. skipping ahead by this site should lead you to the next track. Count the number of tracks you skipped until you have reached the tenth track. you can remove it by deleting the bytes of this track that you would otherwise skip over (include the `MTrk` bytes in your deletion).

That could remove your percussion track, if not, you could try deleting other tracks instead. If this doesn't work then things get a little more complicated.

Exceptions:

- it is possible that this MIDI file has an entire song embedded in a single track, here things get a little more complicated.

The more complicated case:
Within the tracks, there are also track numbers stored for each note, to read those you'll need to make (or find) a full MIDI interpreter. To remove those you'll need to filter out the notes that have that specific track number.

[Source](http://personal.kent.edu/%7Esbirch/Music_Production/MP-II/MIDI/midi_file_format.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some python; there's [this library](https://github.com/mido/mido) for working with MIDI called Mido. It allows you to iterate over the tracks just as SP4CEBAR's answer but at a higher level.

The following function goes over every "message" and checks if there's a channel attribute and whether or not that channel value matches the channel you want to remove.

You could use this to get started:

```python
import mido

def remove_channel_from_midi(input_path, output_path, channel_to_remove):
    try:
        # Load the MIDI file
        midi_file = mido.MidiFile(input_path)
        
        # Create a new MIDI file to store the modified data
        new_midi_file = mido.MidiFile()
        
        for msg in midi_file:
            # Check if the message is on the channel to be removed
            if hasattr(msg, 'channel') and msg.channel == channel_to_remove:
                continue  # Skip this message
            new_midi_file.tracks.append([msg])  # Add the message to the new file
        
        # Save the modified MIDI file
        new_midi_file.save(output_path)
        print(f"Channel {channel_to_remove} removed and saved to {output_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Example usage:
input_midi_path = "input.mid"
output_midi_path = "output.mid"
remove_channel_from_midi(input_midi_path, output_midi_path, channel_to_remove=10)
```